Why use different regression methods?
To keep the question as elementary as possible, what are some of the reasons why we would consider using non-least-squares regression? For example, why would we minimize the $\ell_1$ or $\ell_{\infty}$ norms instead?
To continue with this question, why would we use Bayesian methods instead of least-squares?

My guess is that for some problems $\ell_1$ and $\ell_{\infty}$ regression methods lead to more accurate predictions. Statistics is, fairly often, a "try it and see how it works" discipline. Therefore, my guess is that someone tried $\ell_2$ regression (as one usually does), compared it to $\ell_1$, and for a very specific problem, $\ell_1$ was leading to better predictions.
Is there a better answer than the one above?

On the question of, why use Bayesian regression instead of least-squares? My understanding is that for simple linear regression there is absolutely no benefit. Not only do the two methods give the same answer, but that least-squares is just numerically faster.
I would take a guess and say that Bayesian regression is far more flexible and allows us to handle more general problems that we cannot approach with the least-squares approach. Is that correct?

The short answer is: Different regression methods optimize different cost functions (which is a quantitative way to add a value to particular error that we can make, and we wish to minimize the error, based on how much value we give each level). This can be expressed by the use of different norms, but also different techniques as Bayesian (using a prior) versus Frequentist (independent from any prior). The long answer is: one of many books on this topic, there is no long answer that fits into a SE post.

I have voted to close this as it is too broad. Possibly it can be made community wiki? For the moment closing might be good as this post might get HNQ and attract too many diverse answers relating each to a different question.

For example, only about the single difference between absolute residuals and squared residuals loss functions we have already a very large post Is minimizing squared error equivalent to minimizing absolute error? Why squared error is more popular than the latter?, and similarly for many other differences, e.g. lasso versus ridge or some other regularisation (which is equivalent to Bayesian).

You are asking two separate, though related, questions.
Why use a different loss function than square loss? The square loss elicits conditional means, a pinball loss elicits conditional quantiles, the $\ell_1$ loss is the MAE, a special case of the pinball loss, and it elicits the conditional median. If we are not interested in predicting the conditional mean, but a quantile (e.g., because we want to set safety amounts in demand management), we may want to use a quantile regression (see Koenker's 1978 Quantile Regression textbook, or Koenker et al.'s 2017 Handbook on Quantile Regression) in the first place. ("Better" predictions depend on your error measure, Kolassa 2020.)
Why would we use Bayesian methods? If we have prior information that we want to include in our model, a Bayesian framework provides a very natural way to do this. I do forecasting for retail. We frequently have to deal with new product launches. Sometimes a new product has one or multiple "natural" predecessors. What we do then is to take the promotional coefficients from models fitted using the predecessor product sales, and use these as priors for the new product's model. This allows us to give reasonable forecasts even in situations we have not seen for the new product before (like the first time Christmas comes around), and naturally updates as observations do become available.

That's an interesting application of Bayesian methods that I never considered before (+1)

@ShawnHemelstrand: I could talk at great length on how this is extremely helpful. This "forecasting stuff we haven't seen before" is what our marketing people and the business function at the customers love, and it is absolutely textbook Bayes. The natural regularization provided by priors is what I and the data scientists love, because our customers always feed far too many predictors to the model.

That makes sense. I'll have to look into this sometime. Was learning forecasting at one point, then sadly my recent projects got in the way. Any place to start with Bayesian forecasting? I think all of the basic stuff I learned was under the typical NHST framework.

I can't really recommend anything myself, since what we are doing is so extremely homebrew that I never cracked open a textbook on Bayesian forecasting... There is quite some academic work in Bayesian forecasting (see the International Journal of Forecasting). You could start with this section in the Forecasting Encyclopedia for pointers. Good luck!

Hey @StephanKolassa, by Koenker's textbook, you meant Handbook of Quantile Regression, didn't you? If not, please undo my edit.

@User1865345: thanks, I actually meant the 1978 original textbook, which gave a nice and gentle introduction. I updated, and kept the reference you included.

@ShawnHemelstrand requesting for references on Bayesian forecasting could make a good community wiki question, helpful to other people ;) It looks like it hasn't been already asked.

As Steven already noted, QR is a great example of how loss is considered in a non-OLS context (some discussion on pinball loss in QRs and QGAMs can be found here). Believe it or not, OLS wasn't always the end-all be-all method of regression. Roger Boscovich put forth the framework for quantile regression using absolute residuals in the 1700s, long before Gauss and Legendre independently developed their mean-based versions.
Bayesian methods serve many purposes that frequentist models cannot. Among them are:

Providing more sensible models of probability (rather than the mental gymnastics one has to dance around with a frequentist framework).
Allows for more evidence-based assumptions of the model (using priors) versus letting the data define the model alone. For small samples, Bayesian methods also reduce down the possibility of inaccurate models based on very limited data, which frequentist models are poor equipped at handling.
There are some applications where Bayes just works better. Steve already gave an example with forecasting, but another good example is penalized splines in GAMs. Because of the inherent nature of smooths likely being more wiggly than not, an exponential prior, $\propto \text{exp}(-\lambda\beta^\top S\beta/\sigma^2)$, is applied in the mgcv splines fit in R.


+1. Your second (and third) bullet points sound like you might mention regularization, no?

While I am vaguely familiar with regularization techniques like lasso and ridge, I know less about the Bayesian applications of such models if that is what you are referring to.

It's less commonly discussed. But the priors absolutely regularize a model, compared to a plain vanilla maximum likelihood estimation. (Of course, they regularize "towards the prior mean", not towards zero as most other regularization methods, but that's a feature, not a bug.) Take a beta-Bernoulli example as pretty much the simplest Bayesian illustration and think about it in terms of regularization, comparing the variability of the posterior to what a simple ML estimate would have given us. As I write, this is absolutely crucial in my line of work.
